# Arduino UTFT graphing

Tags: graph, arduino

I use the UTFT library together with the Onewire sketch to plot a temperature graph on an LCD (480 x 320 ):

```
      for (int i=1; i<478; i++)
  {
    myGLCD.drawPixel((1+xi),119-(celsius) );
    xi++;
    delay(100);
  }
```

This works, but I dont understand why is does not work when I remove the for loop. As far as I can read the code, the function should still draw the pixels without the for loop - it draws only one pixels without the loop - 
Besides if I use the loop, the rest of the program is halted until the loop is done, which is bad, since I would like to plot the graph constantly.

Comment: Can you add more information about what doesn't work for you, and what you expect to see instead?

Comment: If I dont use a for loop to plot the graph, my graph only plots 1 pixel, if I use the for loop, the graph plots as it should (480 pixels out the x axis), but it locks down the rest of the program while plotting, this is not what I want, because it would lock up, and prevent the rest of the program to run as it should

Comment: Well, you want to plot 480 points, so you should iterate over 480 points. So.. The loop should stay there. What I don't understand is the need for the delay. Why do you need it? What happens if you remove just the delay?